# Understanding TVS diodes in this application

Tags: tvs, diode-clamp

From [this Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrk45/tidrk45.pdf?ts=1590615980990) you can see they use two TVS diodes at the gate of the first FET to clamp voltages greater than 500V. They do the same in this [other Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrlf7/tidrlf7.pdf?ts=1590616781605).

So basically my question is: TVS diodes do not regulate compared to Zeners, so can this approach continuously clamp high voltages without having a negative impact on the TVS? To my understanding, TVS are mainly used to clamp overvoltages but for a short time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you assume that TVS diodes don't regulate compared to Zeners?  They are avalanche devices just like "Zeners" and you can see the breakdown characteristics in the datasheet.  TVS diodes are just more rugged to handle high peak power events.

The TVS diodes shown form a crude reference for the gate of the upper cascode FET, and clamp the Vgs to a safe value respectively.

The cascode device allows the switching device to be used in an application where it is switching higher voltage that its rating, but it's not necessary to have a precise reference voltage for the gate, so a TVS works fine.